# Как делать адаптивно absolute анимацию

Tags: html, css, анимация, css-animation, адаптивная-верстка

Есть такой блок, с анимацией на `CSS`. Я не знаю как это делать адаптивно. Или на какой-то другой технологии, чтобы работало адаптивно

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.banner__animation {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 302px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

.banner__animation img {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.banner .container {
  padding: 0;
}

.banner__img,
.banner__text {
  position: absolute;
}

.banner__img1 {
  z-index: 1;
}

.banner__img3,
.banner__img2 {
  z-index: 3;
  max-width: 150px;
  left: 62.5%;
  top: 14%;
  transform: rotate(5deg) scale(0.4);
}

.banner__img2 {
  z-index: 2;
  left: 67%;
  top: 23%;
  transform: rotate(40deg) scale(0.4);
}

.banner__text {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  font-size: 30px;
  color: white;
  transform: rotate(-10deg) scale(0.8);
  top: 8%;
  left: 17%;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  opacity: 0;
}

:root {
  --time: 4s;
}

.banner__img4 {
  z-index: 4;
  animation: phraseOne var(--time) infinite;
}

.banner__img5 {
  z-index: 5;
  top: 28%;
  left: 23%;
  animation: phraseTwo var(--time) infinite;
}

.banner__img3 {
  animation: pizzaThree var(--time) infinite;
}

.banner__img2 {
  animation: pizzaThour var(--time) infinite;
}

@keyframes phraseOne {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes phraseTwo {
  23% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  85% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes pizzaThree {
  40% {
    transform: rotate(5deg) scale(0.4);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(5deg) scale(0.4) translate(10%, -30%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(5deg) scale(0.4);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes pizzaThour {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(40deg) scale(0.4);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  70% {
    transform: rotate(40deg) scale(0.4) translate(15%, -40%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  80% {
    transform: rotate(40deg) scale(0.4);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="banner__animation">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMFDa.jpg" class="banner__img banner__img1">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mihinov/mihinov.github.io/f4b8a35268c24b8b6021766797ba1abbac908ba4/assets/img/pizza-piece-1.svg" class="banner__img banner__img2">
      <img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mihinov/mihinov.github.io/f4b8a35268c24b8b6021766797ba1abbac908ba4/assets/img/pizza-piece-1.svg" class="banner__img banner__img3">
      <div class="banner__text banner__img4">Пицца, говорите?</div>
      <div class="banner__text banner__img5">Дайте две!</div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```